# Inserting data into MySQL using $_REQUEST and $_POST not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
$Con=mysql_connect('localhost', '849326_israel', '123456')
    or die('Problemas al seleccionar la base de datos');
mysql_select_db('pruebastest_zzl_registro', $Con)
    or die('Problemas db');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO RegUsuarios (Nombre, Email, PW) values
    ('$_REQUEST[Nombre]', '$_REQUEST[Email]', '$_REQUEST[PW]')",$Con) or die('Problema insertando datos');
```

It's saying...

> Problemas insertando datos

I tried using `$_POST` and it doesn't work!

Thank you very much for helping me I found the error it was a typo

in my database I wrote Emal instead of Email so data could not be processed

Comment: It helps if you can try it in English.

Comment: The code is in Spanish but is normal PHP

Comment: Try running that query directly in SQL and see if it gives you an error.

Comment: @IsraelJiménez Why did you copy your code and place it in a comment?

Comment: I meant run it in your database, like MySql.

Comment: Its saying You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql_query("INSERT INTO RegUsuarios (Nombre,Email,PW) values ('$_REQUEST[No' at line 1

Comment: Check the value of mysql_error before you exit - that will give a clue. Oh, and **don't** use mysql - it's deprecated. Use **mysqli** instead.

Comment: plain text password? you kidding me

Comment: "My code is not working" is NOT an appropriate title for a stack overflow question

Answer (score 3):

[image: xkcd]

Now that that's out of the way, the error message is telling you that there's a problem with the insert query. I would like to suggest you try this:

```
$esc = "mysql_real_escape_string"; // for brevity
mysql_query($q="INSERT INTO `RegUsuarios` (`Nombre`,`Email`,`PW`) VALUES
    ('".$esc($_REQUEST['Nombre'])."','".$esc($_REQUEST['Email'])."',
    '".$esc($_REQUEST['PW'])."')");
if( $e = mysql_error()) {
  die("Error running the query:<br />".$q."<br />Error: ".$e);
}
```

This will dump out the exact query it was trying to run, as well as the exact MySQL error message. In an ideal situation you would log this to a file, instead of displaying it publically, but for development purposes this will do just fine. Note that I've added backticks `` ` `` around your table and column names - many people will tell you they're only needed if you name them something that's a reserved word, but personally I think it's just better to keep to the habit of putting them around all names: not only does it make it easier to visually identify such names (and allow colour-coding to work better), but it also helps avoid some of the more obscure keywords. Additionally, I've changed the `or die` to an actual `if` statement. This will allow you to do more than one thing, such as the logging to a file I mentioned.

Note that you don't need to pass the `$Con` variable around all the time - one of the main upsides of the `mysql` extension is that it will automatically assume the last opened connection.

Comment: Using `$esc` as short-hand for `mysql_real_escape_string` is probably a bad idea. Writing proper `mysql_query` code *should* look ugly because it is ugly. This is why an equivalent example in [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) would be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @tadman Because, of course, `new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebastest_zzl_registro","849326_israel","123456")` is a LOT prettier than `mysql_connect('localhost','849326_israel','123456'); mysql_select_db('pruebastest_zzl_registro');`... /sarcasm

Comment: You only connect once, but you will run hundreds of queries. PDO's `execute` with an array of bindings is about as simple as you can get. There isn't even a connect call in your answer, so I don't know why you'd bring that up.

Comment: And what about passing around that `$PDO` handler into functions and stuff?

Comment: No harder than passing around your MySQL connection handle. Are you really protesting about this? `mysql_query` is a dead interface and it's super clunky to use even at the best of times.

Comment: But that's just it, you *don't* have to pass around a MySQL connection handle. I just don't see any reason not to use `mysql`, other than "most people are too stupid to know how to use it".

Comment: You mean apart from the fact that it's [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and being removed? Please, **DO NOT** encourage people to use it. Maybe it's served PHP well, but let it go.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code.

First, you cannot simply call `"$_REQUEST[Email]"` inside a string like that. It will not get the value of the variable because there are brackets envolved. You have to use `"{$_REQUEST[Email]}"` instead.

Second, sinse the keys `Email` and `Nombre` are strings, its adequate that you properly declare them as such using `"{$_REQUEST['Email']}"`.

In addition, its extremely dangerous to get values that come from the client-side and drop them in your SQL query directly with no filtering. You are exposing your site to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

All and any data coming from client should be properly escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string()` before inserting it in your SQL query.

That being said, your code should be:

```
$nombre = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Nombre']);
$email  = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Email']);
$pw     = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['PW']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO RegUsuarios (Nombre,Email,PW) values
    ('{$nombre}','{$email}','{$pw}')",$Con) or die('Problema insertando datos');
```

It is also a bad practice to store plain text passwords, and mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be soon removed from PHP. Consider storing the passwords as [`sha1()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) hashes, and migrate your code to use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: `"$_REQUEST[Email]"` is fine, that's how you interpolate array values. Not saying it's a good thing to do (I prefer concatenation), but it's not wrong.

Comment: SHA1 can be cracked almost as easily as MD5, so it's best to use a [password specific encryption method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes inside of the `$_POST`

```
$_REQUEST['Nombre']

"INSERT INTO RegUsuarios (Nombre,Email,PW) values
('".$_REQUEST['Nombre']."','".$_REQUEST['Email']."','".$_REQUEST['PW']."')"
```

As people are pointing out this code is open to SQL injection. Consider using PDO instead

Comment: Not when interpolating variables.

Comment: If php doesnt find constant Nobre, it will be converted to string.

Comment: Adding curly braces is only going to make this worse. @Kolink has the right idea.